# How to create a list of seconds in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, datetime-generation

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT timestamp,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM table
GROUP BY timestamp
```

But some timestamps do not show up because there is no data.  Here's an example

```
1:00:00 |  3
1:00:02 | 17
1:00:03 |  2
```

Notice that 1:00:01 is missing.  Is there a way to make the `1:00:01 |   0` appear in the result?

Comment: Why not do this logic in your program? You would be putting less of a load on the DB server.

Comment: @webdestroya: Because the database will scale this better than application code.  Sadly, MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of times, increasing the seconds based on the NUMBERS.id value:

   ```
   SELECT x.*
     FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 SECOND), '%T') 
             FROM numbers n) x
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your table of data based on the time portion:

   ```
      SELECT x.ts AS timestamp,
             COALESCE(COUNT(y.timestamp), 0) AS cnt
        FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 SECOND), '%T') AS ts
                FROM numbers n) x
   LEFT JOIN TABLE y ON y.timestamp = x.ts
    GROUP BY x.ts
   ```